# Traverse more then one list in for loop in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have three lists , I want to use only one for loop for these lists , for that I am using custom filters.I can't use zip because if one of my list empty then zip will be return empty list , so I think I have to use custom filters for this.

**code:**

```
a = []
b = [{"qq":1},{"ww":2},{"ee":3}]
c = [{"rr":4}]
```

Now I want that my custom filter return only one list of these 3 lists.

**Custom filter :**

```
def zip(a,b):
    return a + b
```

**In my templates I have used this :**

1) Working for two lists

```
{% for x in a|zip:b %}    
{% endfor %}
```

2) Not working for three lists:

```
{% for x in a|zip:b|zip:c %}
{% endfor %}
```

3) If make two filters zip1 and zip2 and use this then it also doesn't work :

```
{% for x in a|zip1:b|zip2:c %}
{% endfor %}
```

4) I have also tried to send to lists in one filter so that I can split them there and do my work but that gives me error  **can only concatenate list (not "SafeText") to list**

```
{% for x in a|zip1:'b,c' %}      
{% endfor %}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this using the built-in `add` filter? It can handle adding two lists together - but your custom `zip` filter uses what looks like the same behavior to me, and I'm not sure why that wouldn't work. Try `{% for x in a|add:b|add:c %}` - see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add for an example of adding two lists.

Comment: Actually the problem was in my third array that's by 2nd filter is not working , However I figure out that when u suggest me to use add . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
a = []
b = [{"qq":1},{"ww":2},{"ee":3}]
c = [{"rr":4}]

m = max(len(a), len(b), len(c))

a = (a + [{}]*m)[:m]
b = (b + [{}]*m)[:m]
c = (c + [{}]*m)[:m]

for x, y, z in zip(a, b, c):
    #do something fancy
```

or pass as context variable

```
context = {
    zipped_list: zip(a, b, c),
}
```